# Custom theme for form checkboxes causes AJAX behaviors to not attach

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

I have the following code implemented to override the theming for the checkboxes in a Drupal form.

```
    //themes neighborhood checkboxes with AJAX link wrapper
    function theme_mymodule_neigh_checkboxes($element){
        $output = '';
        foreach($element['element']['#options'] as $key => $val){
            $output .= theme('tfc_search_neigh_checkbox', $element['element'][$key], $key);
        }
        return $output;
    }

    function theme_mymodule_neigh_checkbox($element) {
        _form_set_class($element['element'], array('form-checkbox'));
        $checkbox = '<li><input ';
        $checkbox .= 'type="checkbox" class="ajax-processed" ';
        $checkbox .= 'name="' . $element['element']['#name'] . '" ';
        $checkbox .= 'id="' . $element['element']['#id'] . '" ';
        $checkbox .= 'value="' . $element['element']['#return_value'] . '" ';

        $checkbox .= drupal_attributes($element['element']['#attributes']) . ' />';
        if (!is_null($element['element']['#title'])) {
            $checkbox .=  '<label for="' . $element['element']['#id'] . '">'. $element['element']['#title'] . '</label>';
        }
        $checkbox .= '</li>';
        unset($element['#title']);
        return $checkbox;
    }
```

The form elements look great, but now the AJAX callback associated with the checkboxes does not fire when a checkbox is clicked. THe "ajax-processed" class is not added to the checkbox inputs.

If I don't use the mymodule_checkbox() function, then AJAX works again. It seems like the AJAX behaviors are not being attached to the checkboxes anymore because I'm using a custom theme function.

Any advice?

AJAX looks like this:

```
    function mymodule_form_alter_buildings($form, &$form_state) {
        $output = '';

        $buildings = $form['more']['buildings']['#options'];
        unset($buildings['all']);
        $neigh_buildings = tfc_search_get_buildings($form_state['input']['neighborhoods']);

        foreach ($buildings as $nid => $building) {
            //disable the checkbox if it is not in the neighborhood and add asterisk
            $disabled = '';
            $disabled_msg = '';
            $asterisk = '';
            if (array_key_exists($nid, $neigh_buildings) == FALSE) {
                $disabled = 'disabled="disabled" ';
                $disabled_msg = t('* Building not available in selected neighborhood');
                $asterisk = '*';
            }
            $output .= '<li>
                <input '.$disabled.'id="edit-buildings-'.$nid.'" class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="'.$nid.'" name="buildings['.$nid.']">
                <label class="option" for="edit-buildings-'.$nid.'">'.$building.$asterisk.'</label>
                </li>';
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: Try to control the theme using the prefix/suffix property rather then creating the custom them function.

Comment: thanks, but my designer needs the <li> wrapper around each checkbox to achieve the styling he requires